# Calculate means of individual values in one data frame, merge into second data frame

Tags: r, database, merge, unique, tidyr

I have two biological datasets. Dataset 1 contains individual level measurements labeled by group.

`size <- c(1,5,4,2,6)` 
`group <- c(1,1,2,2,2)`

```
data1 <- data.frame(size, group)
```

Dataset 2 contains mean measurements at the group level, i.e. proportion survived

```
group <- c(1,2) 
p_sx <- c(0.3, 0.76)
data2 <- data.frame(group, p_sx)
```

Q: How would I calculate the mean size per group in dataset 1 and merge that into dataset 2 based on the unique group names? Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge` and `aggregate`:

`merge(aggregate(size ~ group, data1, FUN=mean), data2, by="group")`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data1%>%group_by(group)%>%
                   summarise(mean_size = mean(size))
data2 <- data1%>%left_join(data2,"group")
```

The output is:

```
> data2
# A tibble: 2 × 3
    group mean_size  p_sx
    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1         3  0.30
2     2         4  0.76
```